# Illuminate support collection and getting multiple values by pluck

Tags: php, laravel

I have [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) like this

```
  [  
     {  
        "user_id":1,
        "chat_id":1,
        "chat_hidden":0,
        "access_time":"2017-06-10 00:28:11",
        "name":"Dr. Harley Raynor",
        "image_url":null
     },
     {  
        "user_id":1,
        "chat_id":2,
        "chat_hidden":1,
        "access_time":"2017-06-12 10:59:37",
        "name":"Dr. Harley Raynor",
        "image_url":null
     }
  ]
```

if i want to take only `user_id` from it, and format array like this

```
  [  
     {  
        "user_id":1
     },
     {  
        "user_id":1
     }
  ]
```

i write `Collection()->pluck('user_id')` and everything works fine, but what if i need to take several items? Like `user_id` and `chat_id`? I tried `->pluck('user_id', 'chat_id')`, `->pluck(['user_id', 'chat_id'])` and `->only('user_id', 'chat_id')` nothing seems to work.

Comment: Pluck only works for 1 item, unfortunately

Comment: Yeah, if this is post-retrieval you'll probably want to use `map()`.

Comment: If its not post retrieval, you can use `only()` or `select()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `map`;

```
$myCollection->map(function($item) {
    return [
       'user_id' => $item->user_id,
       ....
    ];
});
```

But if you are building an api, I strongly recommend you to use some sort of transformers such https://github.com/spatie/laravel-fractalto handle inclusion and exclusion in the future as the service mature.